# How do I display the return statement with this occurring error?

Tags: javascript

Just learned what a return statement is and trying to practice with it, but for some reasons it is saying my innerHTML is null?

```js
var x = my_Function(20, 3);

function my_Function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}
document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="return" onload="my_Function()"></p>
```

Comment: Try placing document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = x below the P tag HTML

Comment: Your code is working, no?

Comment: @A.D.Schmidt you just to replace your function name, check my answer, it may fix your issue

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works. https://jsfiddle.net/zx8L5esd/

```
function my_Function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}
document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = my_Function(20, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Made changes in my answer, now you check-in live demo

```js
function my_Function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}
document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = my_Function(20, 3);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="return"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it still gives me the error prompt.

Comment: @A.D.Schmidt just made changes and uploaded the snippet you can check its working

Answer (score 0):

I should have posted where I placed the script source. All the answers you provided worked, but my script was in the head. I moved it to the bottom of the body and it worked fine.